# How to make a fixed floating button to stop at footer in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I would like to create a button using that floats until footer and then stops

1) Button should be  `poisition: fixed;` bottom: 0px when footer is not visible

2) When footer becomes visible, button should just sit on top of footer

The button should handle following cases. 
when states change in angular, when we get data from server the footer is visible for a moment and then the page expands, what will happen then?

when the page has less content and footer is visible, button should sit on top of footer.

How can i do this?

Here is the plunker i started to play around with

http://plnkr.co/edit/SoCBjkUjFICiuTeTPxDB?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post when searching for a similar solution. Without a ready answer, this is what I ended up doing, based on this post https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/04/09/angularjs-sticky-navigation-directive/ .

Basicly you need a `$scope.$watch` to watch for scope change, and an event handler attached to the `onscroll` event.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('stickyBottom', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      // the element box saved for later reference
      var elemRect;
      // element height
      var height = elem[0].clientHeight;
      // element top, will be changed as scope is updated
      var top = 0;

      // updates element's original position
      scope.$watch(function(){
        elemRect = elem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        return elemRect.top + $window.pageYOffset;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        // this is the original element position, save it
        if(!elem.hasClass('fixed-bottom')){
          top = newVal;
        }
        // properly position the element even in `fixed` display
        elem.css('width', elemRect.width);
        elem.css('left', elemRect.left);
        // check position
        toggleClass();
      });

      // toggle `fixed-bottom` class based on element's position
      var toggleClass = function() {
        // the element is hidden
        if (elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + height > $window.innerHeight) {
          elem.addClass('fixed-bottom');
        }
        // the element is visible
        else {
          // the element is visible in its original position
          if (top - $window.pageYOffset + height < $window.innerHeight && elem.hasClass('fixed-bottom')) {
            elem.removeClass('fixed-bottom');
          }
        }        
      }

      // bind to `onscroll` event
      $window.onscroll = function() {
        toggleClass();        
      };

    }
  };
})
;
```

And here's some css:

```
.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this affect without using angular at all by modifying your `style.css`. The simplest solution in this case is just to set the `bottom` parameter of the `#to-top` element to be at minimum higher than the footer, for example:

```
 #to-top {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, The button should be sticking all the way at the bottom when footer is not visible.